# Shannon capacity of some channels

Tags: reference-request, information-theory, entropy

Let $G$ be a finite group. Suppose that $\mu$ is a mesure of probability on $G$. Consider the convolution operator $C: \ell^1(G) \to \ell^1(G)$, $f \mapsto \mu * f$.

What is the capacity of the channel $C$ ?

The capacity of a channel is defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_capacity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a derivation of the capacity (where $h_2(\mu) = -\sum_{x\in G} \mu(x) \log_2(\mu(x))$ is the entropy of the distribution $\mu$)
\begin{align*}
&\max_{p_X} I(X;C(X))\\
=& \max_{p_X} H(C(X)) - H(C(X)|X)\\
=& \max_{p_X} H(C(X)) - h_2(\mu)\\
=& \log_2 |G| - h_2(\mu)
\end{align*}
The third line is because when we know $X$, the distribution of $C(X)$ is $\mu$ with some permutation, the last line is because since $G$ is a group, when $p_X$ is uniform, $\mu\ast p_X$ is also a uniform distribution which has maximal entropy.

---

As a sannity check I always like to check the extreme cases. If $\mu$ is the uniform distribution, then all information is lost, then we get $h_2(\mu)=\log_2|G|$ and the capacity is $0$. When $\mu$ gives probability $1$ to an element, then the channel is deterministic and $h_2(\mu)=0$, which gives a capacity of $\log_2|G|$.

Comment: THANK YOU a lot. I will read that. It is a classical result ? It is written somewhere ?

Comment: No problem, to my knowledge, this isn't classical, I had never seen random variables on groups used in information theory, however I found the setting pretty satisfying and neat, I would be interested in references about that. This proof is very similar to the one for binary symmetric channels (which is basically the same setting with |G|=2). You can see more here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_symmetric_channel#Capacity.

Comment: Thank you. Finally, I think that a convolution channel is a symmetric, see the definition of the book of Cover/Thomas page 189. So the computation of the capacity is given page 190.